# How to append on payload response, the node name used on search ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a ElasticSearch cluster with N nodes, I want receive on response payload either the name of the node used to make the search or the data source node. There are a way to make it?

Answer (score 1):

The node information is available by default on each hit you receive:

```
{
  "_shard" : "[ind][0]",
  "_node" : "TOG1UcrPSvKDxFt2-UeIEw",    <---
  "_index" : "ind",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_source" : {
    ...
  }
```

You can also set `profile: true`:

```
{
  "profile": "true", 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

yielding

```
...
"profile" : {
  "shards" : [
    {
      "id" : "[TOG1UcrPSvKDxFt2-UeIEw][ind][0]",     <--- [node][index][shard]
      "searches" : [
        {
          "query" : [
            {
              "type" : "MatchAllDocsQuery",
              ..
```